# I want to get rid of google finance disclaimer

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

I want to get rid of Google finance disclaimer.
I used the `=GOOGLEFINANCE` formula in a sheet. It triggered the display of a disclaimer at the bottom of the sheet that says:

> Quotes are not sourced from all markets and may be delayed up to 20 minutes. Information is provided 'as is' and solely for informational purposes, not for trading purposes or advice.

How do I get rid of it?
I did it once, I cannot remember how I did it last time. I was unfortunate enough to uninstall and reinstall Chrome, and it came back.

Answer (score 2):

- you can use **Block element** of Adblock Plus:

  ```
  docs.google.com###waffle-disclaimer-content
  ```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, but I dont want to download an ad blocker. Last time I did it naturally, without downloading anything, there must be an option or something.

Comment: Super, worked instantly! I forgot about this neat little feature in ABP, simple but effective to get rid of web annoyances like this one. POOF :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Brave users, you don't have to install AdBlock separately.

From the [How do I block additional page elements?](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018039072-How-do-I-block-additional-page-elements-) article:

> On the `Brave://adblock` page, you will see a `Custom Filters` section at the bottom of the page where the blocked elements will be displayed. Below is the element I blocked above on reddit.com:

Type the following in the box:

```
docs.google.com###waffle-disclaimer-bar
```

I recommend using `waffle-disclaimer-bar` instead of `waffle-disclaimer-content` so that the browser will delete the block too, instead of just hiding the label.

Comment: Update July 28: this trick is not working anymore. I don't know why.